# Is it possible to run integration tests in parallel (Spring boot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, integration-testing

Already has a test environment configured for a specific application (several dozen test classes).

**TestContainers** are also used here.

I see such an **algorithm**:

1. The **Application context** is raised once, for the entire time of working with tests.
2. Also raises one container with **Postgresql**.
3. Since it is impossible to follow the order of **integration tests**, so each test will clean up after itself the data that was written to the database.
4. Find out from the **JVM** how many **processor cores** are allocated to it and create a capacity for the **thread pool** based on this number.
5. Create a **thread pool** in the class with **Application context** (**Executors**....) and issue tasks for running test classes for the threads.

- Is it possible to control the launch of test classes, that is, how to do it from the code ?

6. To run multiple threads simultaneously (according to the **number of cores** in the current system) we can use **CyclicBarrier**.
7. Or you can use a different approach:

Again, you need to know how to run all the **test methods** of this class from an object of the class, with test methods.

So, we create objects of test classes, and using the **Stream API**, then call the **parallel()** method (but here I do not control the number of simultaneously running threads).

What are the options for solving this problem ?

Who has any ideas ?

Comment: Hmm, TestContainers already has Junit integration + Gradle/Maven can execute your Junit tests concurrently.

Comment: Explain in more detail. So it runs multiple integration test threads at the same time ? And does it do this based on the specific number of processor cores allocated to the JVM ?

Comment: By default, Gradle execute only one test at a moment. If you want, Gradle can use the number which you want (May use number of processor cores). I think with maven is the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to my question here

[2.19. Parallel Execution](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution)